# After spliting a string using stringspilt how will I store it in an arraylist?

Tags: java

I have a string variable similar to

```
           String my = "split it";
```

I split this using `split()`.

```
           java.util.Arrays.toString(my.split("\\s+"))
```

The output is [split it]. But I want to store this in an arraylist, in FIRST index split and in SECOND index. Pls let me know how will I can achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(my.split("\\s+"))
```

Comment: This is a *list view* of the backing array, it is unmodifiable and not an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`. (just for clarification!)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

assuming of course that `myArray` is a array from `str.split(..)`

or get an Iterable with Google Guava split method:

```
Iterable split = Splitter.on(",").split(stringToSplit);
```

of course you can replace a comman `','` with regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
String my = "split it";
String[] splitArray = my.split(" ");
List<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitArray));
```

Notice that calling `new ArrayList...` is needed if you want your List to be resizable, since `Arrays.asList()` will return a fixed-size list backed by the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
String my ="String my";
String array[]= my.split(" ");
System.out.println(array[0]);
List<String > list=Arrays.asList(array);
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```